# How to overlay 2 videos at different time over another video in single ffmpeg command?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg command line I want to overlay 2 different videos on top of another (main video) at different time for different duration. I have successfully overlayed 1 video over the main video at specific time and for specific duration using following command:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i first.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS-32/TB[a]; \
                 [0:v][a]overlay=enable=gte(t\,5):eof_action=pass[out]; \
                 [1] scale=480:270 [over]; [0][over] overlay=400:400" \
-map [out] -map 0:a \
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:a copy \
output.mp4
```

How can i modify the same command to apply the same operations on two secondary videos at the same time?

Comment: Your current command is generating two video steams in the output. If you don't want to scale the secondary video, omit `[1] scale=480:270 [over]; [0][over] overlay=400:400`

Comment: i want to scale and position too, what should I do to correct it? (1 stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected version of your command:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i first.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS-32/TB,scale=480:270[a]; \
                 [0:v][a]overlay=400:400:enable=gte(t\,5):eof_action=pass[out]" \
-map [out] -map 0:a \
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:a copy \
output.mp4
```

---

For two secondary videos,

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i first.mp4 -i second.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS-32/TB,scale=480:270[a]; \
                 [2:v]setpts=PTS-32/TB,scale=480:270[b]; \
                 [0:v][a]overlay=400:400:enable=gte(t\,5):eof_action=pass[out0]; \
                 [out0][b]overlay=400:400:enable=gte(t\,5):eof_action=pass[out]" \
-map [out] -map 0:a \
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:a copy \
output.mp4
```

You'll have to adjust the PTS, scale, position and timing of 2nd overlay to see it doesn't overlap with first one.

Comment: **Perfect! Thanks a lot!** Just one more question. What if I want the secondary videos to appear/disappear with fade animation?

Comment: After each scale, add `format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=5:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=20:d=1:alpha=1` `st` is starting time, `d` is duration, both in seconds.

Comment: the last alpha should be alpha=0, no?

Comment: is there a way to automate above answer for arbitrary number of videos? Without writing separate line for each video?

Comment: No, alpha should be 1 since you want the secondary to fade out. ffmpeg can't handle it automatically.