# Mixing various audio and video sources into a single video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I've already read [FFmpeg - Overlay one video onto another video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269387/ffmpeg-overlay-one-video-onto-another-video), [How to overlay 2 videos at different time over another video in single ffmpeg command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333437/how-to-overlay-2-videos-at-different-time-over-another-video-in-single-ffmpeg-co), [FFmpeg - Multiple videos with 4 areas and different play times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515833/ffmpeg-multiple-videos-with-4-areas-and-different-play-times) (and many similar questions tagged `[ffmpeg]` about `setpts`), and **the following code is working**, but I'm sure we can simplify it, and have a more elegant solution.

I'd like to mix multiple sources (image and sound) , with different starting points:

```
t (seconds)           0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13    
test.png              [-------------------------------]
a.mp3                         [-------]
without_sound.mp4                                 [-------------------]        (overlay at x,y=200,200)
b.mp3                                     [---]
with_sound.mp4                    [---------------------------------------]    (overlay at x,y=100,100)
```

This works:

```
ffmpeg -i test.png 
       -t 2 -i a.mp3 
       -t 5 -i without_sound.mp4 
       -t 1 -i b.mp3 
       -t 10 -i with_sound.mp4 
       -filter_complex "
            [0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s0];
            [1]adelay=2000^|2000[s1];
            [2]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+7/TB[s2];
            [3]adelay=5000^|5000[s3];
            [4]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+3/TB[s4];
            [4:a]adelay=3000^|3000[t4];
            [s1][s3][t4]amix=inputs=3[outa];
            [s0][s4]overlay=100:100[o2];
            [o2][s2]overlay=200:200[outv]
       " -map [outa] -map [outv]
       out.mp4 -y
```

but:

- is it normal that we have to use both `setpts` **and** `adelay`? I have tried without `adelay` and then the sound is not shifted. Said differently, is there a way to simplify:

  ```
  [4]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+3/TB[s4];
  [4:a]adelay=3000^|3000[t4];
  ```

  ?
- is there a way to do it with `setpts` and `asetpts` only? When I replaced `adelay=5000|5000` with `asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5/TB` and also for the other one, it didn't give the expected time-shifting (see below)
- in similar questions/answers I often see `overlay=...:enable='between(t,...,...)'`, here it seems it is not needed, why?

More generally, how would you simplify this "mix multiple audio and video" `ffmpeg` code?

---

More details about the second bullet point: if we replace `adelay` by `asetpts`,

```
-filter_complex "
            [0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s0];
            [1]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS+2/TB[s1];
            [2]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+7/TB[s2];
            [3]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5/TB[s3];
            [4]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+3/TB[s4];
            [4:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS+3/TB[t4];
            [s1][s3][t4]amix=inputs=3[outa];
            [s0][s4]overlay=100:100[o2];
            [o2][s2]overlay=200:200[outv]
```

it doesn't work: [3] should begin at 0'05", and [4:a] at 0'03" but they all begin at the same time than [1], i.e. at 0'02".

It seems that `amix` only takes the first `asetpts` in consideration, and discards the others; is it true?

Comment: "*is there a way to simplify*" Ran out of time to look at this today, but one lazy suggestion is to use `adelay=5s:all=1` so you can work in seconds and not have to know the number of channels (make sure your ffmpeg isn't too old or it won't work).

Answer (score 2):

> is it normal that we have to use both setpts and adelay?

Yes, the former is for video streams; the latter, for audio. asetpts is not suitable for use with amix since the latter ignores starting time offsets. adelay fills in with silence from 0 to the desired offset.

> I often see overlay=...:enable='between(t,...,...)', here it seems it is not needed, why?

Overlay syncs its main and overlay video frames by timestamps. `enable` is needed if one wishes to disable overlay when synced frames are available for both inputs.